# Maintaining express sessions when moving between static and dynamic pages on client side

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, express-session

I am trying to set up express sessions for user authentication.
I have a node.js backend, and angular and static page front end (two front ends).

My node backend accepts username and password for authentication on my route
as a post request `http://localhost:3000/users/login`

My journey is as follows:

1. User is presented with a static front end login page, (this is designed by injecting vue.js with axios on a static html page), wherein he requests a log in with his credentials. The client frontend is hosted on `http://localhost:3011/`

2. The application will now send a post request to `http://localhost:3000/users/login` to verify the credentials. 

3. If the credentials are valid, the server will create a new session (express-session) using req.session. In this session, I also store my token that I use to authenticate the user for any subsequent requests (this token is saved in the db and verified for all further requests). The server will then respond with a 200 OKAY status.

4. Once the vue application gets a positive response, the client will redirect the application to `http://localhost:3000/` where I have angular application in the dist folder.

If, in POSTMAN, I do a post to `http://localhost:3000/users/login` and then do a GET on `http://localhost:3000/`, I can see the token in the logs when the server responds to the GET request. 

But, if i send a post request to `http://localhost:3000/users/login`  from my vue application, and then redirect to `http://localhost:3000/` on successful authentication, I cannot see the token in the logs.

Code Snippet on the client side (Vue)

```
submit() {
      this.errMsg = "";
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:3000/users/login", {
          user: this.user,
          password: this.password
        })
        .then(response => {
          window.location = "http://localhost:3000/";
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          this.errMsg = err.data.statusText;
        });
    }
```

Code inside login on server side

```
router.route("/login").post((req, res) => {
  let { user, password } = req.body;
  merchant_table
    .findOne({ attributes: ["id"], where: { email, password } })
    .then(result => {
      if (result) {
        let token = 12345;
        token_table
          .create({ m_id: result.id, token })
          .then(result => {
            req.session.user = result.token;
            console.log("session is", req.session); //THIS SHOWS THE TOKEN
            res.status(200).json({status:"OKAY!"})
          });
      } else {
        res.status(401).json({status:"Invalid User!"})
      }
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
});
```

Code inside the request API for `http://localhost:3000/`

```
app.use("/", function(req, res) {
  console.log("Session is", req.session); //THIS SHOWS THE TOKEN FOR POSTMAN, NOT WHEN WORKING WITH VUE
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/dist/index.html");
});
```

Since the axios post request and the subsequent redirect is to `http://localhost:3000/` I expected the token to be maintained. But it seem to assume this as a new connection. Is this approach wrong? Is there a way to keep track of the token on redirect? I need the token only once, because then I will store it in the angular application and send it for any other requests that I need.
How do I go about with this?

Comment: You're hosting your authentication and your frontend on two different ports? Is that a typo in the top of your answer?

Comment: There is a vue based front end which is on 3011, and the angular front end on 3000.